# minted does not break lines based on breakbefore

Tags: line-breaking, minted

I want minted to break lines after ".", so I use `breakbefore=.` and `breakbytokenanywhere=true` but minted still breaks the line before "." instead of after. What am I missing?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{minted}
\usepackage{upquote}
\setminted{fontsize=\small, breaklines=true, breakbefore=., breakafter={,}, breakbytokenanywhere=true, frame=single, numbers=left, numbersep=5pt, highlightcolor={red!20}, fontfamily=tt}
\begin{document}
\begin{minted}{python}
results = pd.DataFrame(data=results,columns=['Clusters C','Intertia']).set_index('Clusters')
\end{minted}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer and comments by Marijn cover most of what is going on here: `breakbytokenanywhere` probably isn't wanted (it allows many break locations in addition to `.`), and `breakbefore` has less precedence than breaking at spaces (it's based on `\discretionary`).

It's possible to disable breaking at spaces by replacing them with non-breaking spaces via the options `showspaces, space=~`.  `showspaces` makes the space character visible, and then `space` swaps the default visible space character for a non-breaking, invisible space.

Answer (score 1):

You also specify `breakbytokenanywhere`, it looks like this gets priority over `breakbefore`. Removing this setting leads to breaking before `.`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{minted}
\usepackage{upquote}
\setminted{fontsize=\small, breaklines=true, breakbefore=., breakafter={,}, frame=single, numbers=left, numbersep=5pt, highlightcolor={red!20}, fontfamily=tt}
\begin{document}
\begin{minted}{python}
results = pd.DataFrame(data=results,columns=['Clusters','Intertia']).set_index('Clusters')
\end{minted}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Note also that the `breakafter` comma is in a group, so `breakafter={,}`.

Comment: Hello Marijn, thanks for your reply. In this example it works, but if you had a space anywhere (see my code update) it doesn't work anymore: minted break the line just after the space and doesn't look for a better "."

Comment: @Nicolas It seems spaces also have priority over `breakbefore`, so the algorithm would be 'find a space to break, if there is one then break on that space, if not then find a `breakbefore` character and break on that'. Looking at the examples in the manual the `breakbefore` and `breakafter` options are intended for situations where there are no spaces to break on and you still want some control over where the breaks occur (note that I'm not fully sure this actually is how it works but that is what I conclude from the observed behavior).

Comment: So this means that actually everything in the code works fine, except that spaces have the priority over anything...

Comment: @Nicolas It's possible to disable breaking at spaces by replacing them with non-breaking spaces via `showspaces, space=~`.

Comment: @G.Poore it worked! can you post your answer so that I validate it?